# Inserting only one band in Google Earth Engine and modify that band

Tags: google-earth-engine, heat-map

I am trying to see the heat inside Laos watershed and I would like to only use Band 10 in Landsat image. But the watershed is located within the intersection of four different Landsat images. So if I want to process "Band 10" for the four images, how to process that in GEE?

This is my snippet code.

```
 //Display laos admin from shapefile
var laosadmin;
Map.addLayer(laosadmin, {color: 'green'}, 'laosadmin');

//import image colllection
var lcCol = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR');

//Filter image by date and region of interest
var filterdate = lcCol.filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-03-01').filterBounds(laoswshed);


//Display landsat into the screen
Map.addLayer(filterdate);
//Display watershed area
Map.addLayer(laoswshed);
//Center the view to Laos Admin for macrosight
Map.centerObject(laosadmin);

//see the list of the date at the console
print(filterdate);

//Filter image collection by the IMAGE_QUALITY property
var filtered = lcCol
.filterMetadata('IMAGE_QUALITY','equals',2);
print(filtered)


// I just randomly pick one landsat image ID from the image collection, loading one image
//var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_128046_20190209');

//Convert the brightness temperature (Kelvin 0.1) to Celsius 
var tempC = image.select("B10")
.multiply(0.1)
.subtract(273.5);

//Load and See the different of pixel value in raw landsat and tempC
Map.addLayer(tempC);
```

And here is my snippet script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/c28efdb63bd2733d7fa27bf2e48e58e6

Specifically, the var image is only for one Landsat image. But I want to process for four Landsat images simultaneously. Is there any suggestion?

```
//Convert the brightness temperature (Kelvin 0.1) to Celsius 
var tempC = image.select("B10")
.multiply(0.1)
.subtract(273.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

The link to your code doesn't work, and I not sure I understand your question completely. I think you want to convert all images in your image collection to Celsius? To do that, you map over the collection:

var imagesInCelcius = filtered.map(function (image) {
  return image.select("B10")
  .multiply(0.1)
  .subtract(273.5);
});

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b5925db4c674f9deb82af80469d64375